# Missing host to link to error in Rails 5.2.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I've gone through every stackoverflow question regarding this error:
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rails+Missing+host+to+link+to

All the posts mention the same solution, which is to add the config in the environment file you're working on. In my case, I added to my development.rb:

```
config.active_storage.service = :local
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "localhost", port: "3000" }
MyApp::Application.default_url_options = Robson::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options = Robson::Application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options
```

But I still get the infamous error message:

```
Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

In the following locations if I try to open a file that I uploaded locally:

```
 open(file.service_url)
```

or if I try to access the files from ActiveAdmin (I called the model "Attachments" and I'm using ActiveStorage)

```
column(:file) {|a| link_to a.file.filename, a.file.service_url}
```

I also tried setting "host" in a dictionary as a parameter in the above "link_to" and "open" functions. I also tried "only_path".

Nothing works.

Any help would be appreciated!

P.S.: my active storage config:

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>

test:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("tmp/storage") %>

amazon:
  service: S3
  access_key_id: S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID
  secret_access_key: S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  bucket: S3_BUCKET
  region: S3_REGION
```

**UPDATE**

Trying to use rails_representation_url but getting an error *undefined method 'variation' for ActiveStorage::Attached*

```
class Attachment < ApplicationRecord
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  has_one_attached :file
....
def with_uploaded_file
  tempfile = Tempfile.open([file.filename.to_s, File.extname(file.filename.to_s)]) do |file_temp|
  file_temp.binmode unless file.content_type =~ /text/
  require 'open-uri'
  # file_temp.write(open(file.service_url).read)
  file_temp.write(open(rails_representation_url(file, only_path: true)).read)
  file_temp
end
begin
  yield(tempfile)
ensure
  tempfile.unlink
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded Rails from 5.1 to 5.2 and had same problem.

Solution: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32866

So when you have your ActiveRecord variant instead of

```
   variant.service_url
```

do

```
    rails_representation_url(variant, only_path: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this, but I get the below error. I updated the code in the question to show you exactly how I'm using your answer.

`undefined method 'variation' for #<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x000055f7a78d9b50>`

Comment: @anode84 I notice that the error message mentions the word `variation` but the method that should be used is `variant`